# Timers within Android Services?

Tags: android, service, timertask

I have an Android Service that accesses the database about once per minute. Is there a way to, within this service, start another process within a timer that executes once every 12  hours? Right now I have the following code within my service but this code is executed at the same rate as the service:

```
UPDATE_INTERVAL = (1000*60)*60*12;
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
                    @Override

                    public void run(){   

                        if(!parseDailyData(AppStatus.getConsumer(), AppStatus.getProvider(), client, dayData))
                        {
                            Log.v(TAG, "no parse day set");  
                        }
                        getTopPeople();
                    }

                }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an Android Service that accesses the database about once per minute.

Hopefully, this is only running while your application is in the foreground, or because the user explicitly asked for this service to run.

> Is there a way to, within this service, start another process within a timer that executes once every 12 hours?

Use `AlarmManager` for something that will occur every 12 hours. You might even consider using it for something that will run every 1 minute, so you do not necessarily tie up memory all of the time.

Comment: Will I need to create a separate service to start the alarm process? Or, can I call the 12-hour repeating alarm from the service that runs once per minute? Or, is it best to create two alarms within the service: one to execute once per minute and the other to execute once per 12 hours?

Comment: @user836200: The service does the periodic work. Setting up your alarm schedule using `AlarmManager` usually happens elsewhere.